# How can make a function object similar to the one in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, object

I have 2 questions, please give me some advice.

I am trying to find out how jQuery works.  After reading its code, I found that jQuery is simply returning `this` from its function object.  There's an easy example around line `2975`.

So it will be similar to this code below :

```
var a = new function a ( ) {
        return this;
    };
a[0] = document.querySelectorAll( 'div#1' ) ;

console.log(a)

var b = new function ( ) {
        this[0] = document.querySelectorAll( 'div#1' )  ;
        return this;
    };

console.log(b)

console.log(jQuery('#1'))
```

However about when I check the console,

[image]

as you can see, jQuery doesn't have `jQuery` in front of the object, and the object is more like Array it quoted by `[ ]` and the prototype is `Object[0]` .

and `__proto__: Object[0]` has no `constructor` inside.

My questions are how does jquery makes a new function instance without the function name in front, and what is this `__proto__: Object[0]` ?

Thank you very much!

Comment: do you know what an anonymous functions/object looks like?

Comment: @madalinivascu anonymous functions/object will display 'Object' in the front !

Comment: Which version of jQuery are you using? I'm trying to find what you refer to as line 2975

Comment: It's the latest one, 3.0

Answer (score 0):

I finally found how they did it.

`$(this)` or `$(selector)` is actually return Array object!!!! I still couldnt find in which part jQuery does so but what they do is like below

```
var a = new function a ( ) {
        return this;
    };

var b = [ document.querySelectorAll( 'div#1' ) ] ;

b.__proto__ = new a;


console.log (b)
```

Above will return alike object like jQuery.

The difference is `b.__proto__` is a `insteadof Object[0]`

Please advise if I am wrong...